# Script to check if a git commit was the first of a day

Tags: linux, git, shell, travis-ci

the task is as follows:

- on a build server (travis-ci) I'd like to check if a push was a first during the day
- if yes, copy the master branch to a another one (daily snapshot)

Best regards

Comment: Why not just add a nightly tag, regardless of whether there were new commits? Neither is very useful, as Git makes it easy to revert to any point in time.

Comment: i need to push commit changes to this tag on a timely basis, i do only have a build server that is triggered on commit, no cron :/

Comment: Track the date in your post-receive hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your build script you could dump the date in a file. And at the beginning, you could compare it. It could looks like:

```
currentDate=$(date +%D)
isFirstBuildOfTheDay=true

if [ -e last_date_build.txt ]; then
  if [ $currentDate = $(cat last_date_build.txt) ]; then
      isFirstBuildOfTheDay=false
  fi
fi

if $isFirstBuildOfTheDay; then
   #Take a daily snapshot
fi

#Perform the actual build

echo $currentDate > last_date_build.txt
```

---

Edit to take the comment into account:

If you can't keep files, what about recording this date on a tag?

For example:

```
currentDate=$(date +%F)
dailyTag=daily_$currentDate
if ! git rev-parse $tag >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  #Take a daily snapshot
  git tag $dailyTag
  git push --tags
fi
```

Comment: thanks for the proposal, but i can not dump the file -- the vm is destroyed... i need to work with the commit log somehow

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer to propose another solution without files

Comment: better! can i do it with a date in a commit description? I do not want to spam our tags

Comment: Perhaps, but can't think of an easy way to do it, in particular because each build should be able to finnd the last commit built. My solution propose to do it with either file or tags. I don't see how it could be done cleanly with commit description, but it's maybe because I lake imagination here.

Comment: I ended with something like "git log --since=today.midnight | grep commit | wc -l" and if it is "1" i start the push